# You cannot combine custom titles with other features

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using custom title in my android application, by calling `getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);` in my activity.

In my manifest I have set the theme like- `android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >`

The AppTheme in style.xml -

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">40dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
</style>
```

App base theme inherits - `android:Theme.Holo.Light`

This code runs good on devices having Android version less than 4, but when I try to run it on above 4 or 4.0 device I get error as - "You cannot combine custom title with other title features" I went thoroughly in StackOVerflow discussions, but unable to resolve the issue.

Any suggestions on this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done !!

Resolved this error by adding `<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>` in

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">40dip</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>`

Thanks !! :)